# How to detect the finish event of video playing in HTML5Webview android

Tags: java, android, android-webview, html5-video

I have coded to play a video in HTML5webview in android. But i cant able to get the finish event of the playing video. Is there any way to get the finish event of the video that is playing in HTML5webview since i have to play another video once the first video that is playing is finished!

Code i have used to play video in HTML5Webview

Test.java

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    HTML5WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            //  copyAssets("file:///storage/emulated/0/video/1470403485393");
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///storage/emulated/0/video1.mp4");

        }


        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            // autoplay when finished loading via javascript injection
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("onPageFinished-called");
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
            }
        });


        setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mWebView.stopLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (mWebView.inCustomView()) {
                mWebView.hideCustomView();
                //  mWebView.goBack();
                //mWebView.goBack();
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void copyAssets(String path) {
        String[] files = null;

        try {
            files = getAssets().list(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (files.length == 0)
            copyFile(path);
        else {
            File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);

            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                copyAssets(path + "/" + files[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(String filename) {
        InputStream in = null;

        File file;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = getAssets().open(filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "ERROR WITH in = getAssets().open: " + filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("", "ERROR WITH out = new FileOutputStream(file);");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] data;

        try {
            data = new byte[in.available()];

            in.read(data);
            out.write(data);

            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML5WebView

```
public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

    private Context mContext;
    private MyWebChromeClient                   mWebChromeClient;
    private View                                mCustomView;
    private FrameLayout                         mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback  mCustomViewCallback;

    private FrameLayout                         mContentView;
    private FrameLayout                         mBrowserFrameLayout;
    private FrameLayout                         mLayout;

    static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

        mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

        mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
        mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

        mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

        // Configure the webview
        WebSettings s = getSettings();
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //  s.setSavePassword(true);
        s.setSaveFormData(true);

        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

       /* msetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            // autoplay when finished loading via javascript injection
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
        });*/

        setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        // enable navigator.geolocation
        // s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        // s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/org.itri.html5webview/databases/");

        // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mContentView.addView(this);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public FrameLayout getLayout() {
        return mLayout;
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
                goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on ShowCustomView");
            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            System.out.println("customview hideeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HTML5WebView.this.goBack();
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "set it to webVew");
        }


        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getVideoLoadingPregressView");

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }


    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

custom_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/error_console"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

video_loading_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:text="@string/loading_video"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Got stuck with this cameo